# Why there is no easy way to unscope associations in rails (mongoid)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, has-and-belongs-to-many, soft-delete

I tried to google and read about it, but I could not find an easy solution or a very good answer in regard to this topic. There are many similar questions, solving people's problems. I could not figure out how to solve mine and on top of that I still wonder why nobody did not solve that yet. It is such a common problem I think.

---

I am using Rails 4 and Mongoid 4 with Mongoid Paranoia.
I want to implement a soft deletion for `User`. That works.

However I have an `Event` model which `has_and_belongs_to_many :users, inverse_of: nil`.

When I soft delete a user, who is a user of the event, then I seem to fail to find a way to have this user being fetched by default. Soft deleted users are not fetched, because of the default scope on User with `deleted_at: nil`.

Anyone enlightening out there ?

How to get started to implement something similar to what ActiveRecord offers:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users, -> { *a defined scope* }
```

Comment: Have you tried an SCI approach? Then you'd be automatically filtering on `_type` and your associations could link to the base class. Smells a bit rotten but maybe it will be sufficient. You could also try bypassing the associations and do it by hand (which also smells awful...).

Comment: @muistooshort thanks, but I am really trying to find the best/easiest solution. I'd like to avoid rotten...

Comment: Fair enough, just throwing out some last resort options. Could you replace `deleted_at` with a `status` flag that everything will have and then add a filter to the relationship (`:status.ne => nil` for example) that will undo the default scope? I tend to avoid default scopes completely.

Comment: Good idea @muistooshort. In that case I would need to overwrite the delete function (and maybe others) for that model I think. So that it defines a status field. I might consider that. Still smells like a little hack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if I am understanding you completely, but shouldn't calling another scope that utilizes `unscoped` do what you need. [Docs here](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Scoping/Default/ClassMethods/unscoped).

```
default_scope { where(deleted_at: nil) }

scope :some_other_scope, -> { unscoped.where(something_else: true) }
```

**Edit**

Ah, I see. Not the most elegant way but if you're set on not changing the `default_scope` of the User model; perhaps:

```
# Event model
def all_users
    User.unscoped.where(event: self)
end
```

Comment: It's about unscoping association by default, not the model scope itself.

Comment: See the edited answer above. This will allow you to call `@event.all_users` which will return ALL users of that event.